# ActionBarSherlock Doesn't Compile No More

Tags: java, scala, actionbarsherlock, sbt

I am using ActionBarSherlock, Scala, Sbt and android-plugin. Everything was working correctly when all of the sudden it wouldn't compile. I used git to fall back to previous commits that were working before and it would still throw me the following 12 errors. Then, I remembered that my Mac OS updated and I checked what was updated. It seems my Java has been updated from 1.6.0_37 to 1.6.0_41 with the new Java for OS X 2013-001.

Anyone else using this particular version is having problems? How should I go about fixing this issue?

```
> compile
[info] extracting apklib actionbarsherlock-4.2.0.apklib
[info] Wrote /Users/Laimiux/scala-rest-client/target/scala-2.9.2/src_managed/main/scala/com/limeblast/mydeatree/TR.scala
[info] generated 84 source files from 1 apklibs
[info] Compiling 36 Scala sources and 87 Java sources to /Users/Laimiux/scala-rest-client/target/scala-2.9.2/classes...
[warn] /Users/Laimiux/scala-rest-client/src/main/scala/IdeaEditActivity.scala:32: value FILL_PARENT in object LayoutParams is deprecated: see corresponding Javadoc for more information.
[warn]     getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
[warn]                                        ^
[error] /Users/Laimiux/scala-rest-client/target/scala-2.9.2/src_managed/main/java/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragment.java:11: OnCreateOptionsMenuListener is not a member of com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity
[error] import static com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.OnCreateOptionsMenuListener;
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/Laimiux/scala-rest-client/target/scala-2.9.2/src_managed/main/java/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragment.java:15: not found: type OnCreateOptionsMenuListener
[error] public class SherlockFragment extends Fragment implements OnCreateOptionsMenuListener, OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener, OnOptionsItemSelectedListener {
[error]                                                           ^
[error] /Users/Laimiux/scala-rest-client/target/scala-2.9.2/src_managed/main/java/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragment.java:13: OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener is not a member of com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity
[error] import static com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener;
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/Laimiux/scala-rest-client/target/scala-2.9.2/src_managed/main/java/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragment.java:15: not found: type OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener
[error] public class SherlockFragment extends Fragment implements OnCreateOptionsMenuListener, OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener, OnOptionsItemSelectedListener {
[error]                                                                                        ^
[error] /Users/Laimiux/scala-rest-client/target/scala-2.9.2/src_managed/main/java/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragment.java:12: OnOptionsItemSelectedListener is not a member of com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity
[error] import static com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.OnOptionsItemSelectedListener;
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/Laimiux/scala-rest-client/target/scala-2.9.2/src_managed/main/java/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragment.java:15: not found: type OnOptionsItemSelectedListener
[error] public class SherlockFragment extends Fragment implements OnCreateOptionsMenuListener, OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener, OnOptionsItemSelectedListener {
[error]                                                                                                                      ^
[error] /Users/Laimiux/scala-rest-client/target/scala-2.9.2/src_managed/main/java/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockListFragment.java:11: OnCreateOptionsMenuListener is not a member of com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity
[error] import static com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.OnCreateOptionsMenuListener;
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/Laimiux/scala-rest-client/target/scala-2.9.2/src_managed/main/java/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockListFragment.java:15: not found: type OnCreateOptionsMenuListener
[error] public class SherlockListFragment extends ListFragment implements OnCreateOptionsMenuListener, OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener, OnOptionsItemSelectedListener {
[error]                                                                   ^
[error] /Users/Laimiux/scala-rest-client/target/scala-2.9.2/src_managed/main/java/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockListFragment.java:13: OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener is not a member of com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity
[error] import static com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener;
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/Laimiux/scala-rest-client/target/scala-2.9.2/src_managed/main/java/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockListFragment.java:15: not found: type OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener
[error] public class SherlockListFragment extends ListFragment implements OnCreateOptionsMenuListener, OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener, OnOptionsItemSelectedListener {
[error]                                                                                                ^
[error] /Users/Laimiux/scala-rest-client/target/scala-2.9.2/src_managed/main/java/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockListFragment.java:12: OnOptionsItemSelectedListener is not a member of com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity
[error] import static com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.OnOptionsItemSelectedListener;
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/Laimiux/scala-rest-client/target/scala-2.9.2/src_managed/main/java/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockListFragment.java:15: not found: type OnOptionsItemSelectedListener
[error] public class SherlockListFragment extends ListFragment implements OnCreateOptionsMenuListener, OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener, OnOptionsItemSelectedListener {
[error]                                                                                                                              ^
[warn] /Users/Laimiux/scala-rest-client/src/main/scala/NewIdeaActivity.scala:38: value FILL_PARENT in object LayoutParams is deprecated: see corresponding Javadoc for more information.
[warn]     getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
[warn]                                        ^
[warn] two warnings found
[error] 12 errors found
[error] (Scala-Rest-Client/compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed Feb 27, 2013 11:32:58 PM
>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what caused this problem, but I fixed it. I first tested creating regular Android Project and adding ActionBarSherlock. It compiled! Then, I figured to create a new Scala Android project where I added ActionBarSherlock. It compiled as well! So, I copied all the old resources, java/scala files. Updated the AndroidManifest. Project compiled, build and is working again!

Seems that my project folder got corrupted or something of that matter.

Comment: Actually the problem was that Scala files were compiling before Java files. In sbt Build.scala, put compileOrder := CompileOrder.JavaThenScala,